# echo/printf incomplete command at bash terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, echo

At the BASH prompt I can `find` files then append `xargs` to do further stuff. e.g. `find ... | xargs rm {}`

However, sometimes there is a manual intermediate step: I use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to refine the `find` results.

I would like to use this filtered list of files to create an **incomplete** `xargs` command at the terminal.

For example, if my `find` command produces 
`file1` `file2` `file3`, and my [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) narrows this down to `file2` `file3`, I would like the script to create an incomplete line at the terminal like this:

`file2 file3 |xargs -0 --other-standard-options`

but i don't want the command to *flush* (I don't know what the correct term is) as if I had pressed `enter`.  I want to be able to complete the command myself (e.g. `rm {}`), after seeing the list of files printed on the line.

The `find` command will need to use the `print0` option.

I suppose the script would look something like this:

`find . | fzf -m | *echo incomplete xargs command*.`

the `echo -n` command is not what I want: it still passes the command to BASH shell.

Maybe there is a better way of using `find`, then manually checking and filtering, then executing a command like `rm` or `mv`, and if so, that would be an acceptable answer.

The number of files I need to be able to deal with after the filtering is small (<100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work, leaving the user to complete the command at the prompt:

```
out=$(find . |fzf -m )
prefix="echo  ";
suffix="| xargs  ";
files="$(echo "${out}" | sed -e 's:^\.:"\.:g' -e 's:$:":g'|tr '\n' ' ' )";
cmd="${prefix}${files}${suffix}" ;
read -e -i "$cmd"; eval "$REPLY";
```

Explanation: `fzf` outputs filenames which I wrap in double quotes for the sake of safety; the terminal command I want to create looks like this:

`echo "file1" "file2" "file3"|xargs ....`

All the real credit goes to @meuh [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213799/can-bash-write-to-its-own-input-stream)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like fzf has some evn settings that can be used to filter the set of data that comes back. There is also options env as well. I would take a look at the following evn variables: 
FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND and FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS.

FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND will allow you to use a different command to filter down your file set.  Check out the following [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#git-ls-tree-for-fast-traversal)

Meaning you may not need to use find and pipe that to the fzf command. You could just start with the fzf command itself and set the proper evn variable.

To use the interactive mode to remove and review files on the same line you could do something like the following.

```
find . -type f -name '*test*' | fzf -m | xargs rm
```

Comment: the environmental variables sure do help; but I'd like to write the xargs after I have seen the list (unlike your example), because I won't know the command until I see the files which are selected.

Comment: I would look at the [External Programs](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#executing-external-programs) bindings, and see if you can call fzf in interactive mode slect the files and execute a move or delete command.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name '*test*' | fzf -m); do 
   read -p ".... ${f} Enter command to insert on the dots "
   echo "$REPLY ${f}"
   $REPLY "${f}"
done
```

Comment: 1) this requires me to type in the command for each file.  I would like to do the same command for all files
2) it needs to cope with print0 because of \n in some filenames.
3) by way of explanation: is there no way to type an incomplete command (i.e. what bash does when you select a previous command from history, but allows you to edit it)?

Comment: I don't know about the history. When you want one command for all files, can you ask for that command before you call `find  .. print0 .. | xargs .. $REPLY .. `?

Comment: I'd like to see the results of the `find`  before I determine the command.

Comment: You can call `find` first before processing the data, ask for the command and call `find` again, now with the for-loop or `xargs`. Use a `mtime` flag when you only want to process files you have seen before entering the command.